# Is there a solution for automated / scripted Google AppEngine Java deployment?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'd like to automate / script deployment of my app on AppEngine Java. As far as I can tell, nobody has come up with a good open solution that is reusable... or is there?

Ideally, it would do the following tasks:

1. Copy the war folder to a temporary directory.
2. Run any tasks that need to be run (we Uglify our JS code in this step).
3. Run 'appcfg resource_limits_info war' to authenticate with google and store the cookie.  (Because of this: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7653)
4. Call 'appcfg update' to upload new version, using current datetime as version (2012-01-01-1411).
5. Warmup instance by hitting http://2012-01-01-1411.appid.appspot.com url.
6. Call 'appcfg set_default_version' to switch to new version if #5 succeeds. If not, repeat #5 until it does.
7. Automatically delete an old version to keep things tidy. (Impossible, feature request: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2723)

I can/will write this myself, but I'm wondering if anyone else has been down this path before or would like to collaborate on a solution that lots of people can use.

Comment: It seems a pretty much customized solution; have you checked Ant or Maven?

Comment: Would you like to suggest a less custom solution to solving the problem? Ant and Maven are tools, not solutions.

Comment: I don't need to know what tools to use, I need to know if anyone has a good solution to the problem. The tooling is irrelevant.

Comment: You should write this by yourself and post it as an answer, I'll upvote it for sure. Good luck!

Comment: Yup. We've now implemented most of the steps above as part of an Ant build and it is working pretty well. I'll try to get around to documenting it here soon.

Comment: Have you tried the deployment tools provided in eclipse?  The eclipse plug-in has a one click solution for deploying your app to GAE.  You can even add in post-build steps to uglify before deployment.

Comment: I'm looking at the plugin and I don't see anything about post-build steps or the ability to automatically version my app correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the core of the ant targets that have been working really well for us. The only part that isn't implemented in the steps above is #7 since that isn't possible with AppEngine yet. We've found that using the date as a version number has been really handy for keeping track of deployments.

```
<target name="auth">
    <java classname="com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg" inputstring="${appengine.pass}" fork="true">
        <sysproperty key="appengine.sdk.root" value="${appengine.sdk.dir}" />
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${appengine.sdk.dir}/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
        </classpath>
        <arg value="--email=${appengine.email}" />
        <arg value="resource_limits_info" />
        <arg value="war" />
    </java>
</target>

<target name="optimize">
    <delete dir="${staging.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${staging.dir}" />

    <copy todir="${staging.dir}">
        <fileset dir="war">
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/classes/**" />
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/appengine-generated/**" />
            <exclude name="include.js" />
            <exclude name="js/app/**" />
            <exclude name="js/tmpl/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="${staging.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/classes.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" />

    <exec executable="./scripts/optimize.sh">
        <env key="PATH" value="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin" />
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="deploy-prod" depends="auth, optimize">
    <property name="appid" value="voost0" />
    <tstamp>
        <format property="vnum" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm"/>
    </tstamp>

    <echo message="Deploying to version: ${vnum}" />

    <appcfg action="update" war="${staging.dir}">
        <options>
            <arg value="--application=${appid}" />
            <arg value="--version=${vnum}" />
        </options>
    </appcfg>

    <get src="http://${vnum}.${appid}.appspot.com/ping" dest="${build.dir}/warmup-garbage" verbose="true" />
</target>

<target name="deploy-prod-switch" depends="deploy-prod">
    <appcfg action="set_default_version" war="${staging.dir}">
        <options>
            <arg value="--application=${appid}" />
            <arg value="--version=${vnum}" />
        </options>
    </appcfg>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use their Gradle or Maven plugin

Gradle:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

Maven:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven